# What materials can be used to construct a massive aerially placed quantum random computer?

Tags: science-based, physics, robots, machine-cult

I have a quantum signalling system which is kind of steam-gothic, where some rune/planetary/laser display/flappy doors thing/bouncy ball/dog in a wheel/runic digits/sky balloons/light displays have to encode a number between one and 365.

Is it possible to design a big metal quantum signalling machine 20 stories high, which makes a visible display above the skyline of many roofs, that humans couldn't find a way to change its random result?

Comment: What if they graffiti the display to add a 1 to each result, =D

Comment: Unobtanium obviously.

Comment: of course there are scientific paper on the falsafiebility of phisical chaos machines, its related to voting security theory, just like marbles can follow random paths based on the butterfly effect, I need a chaos capable gyroscope or something, which can't be falsified. It's not more crazy that suggesting that there can be an unfalsifiable digital voting machine.

Comment: No no no. Changing result has nothing to do with chaos theory, quantum effects et cetera! All it takes is cutting the cord between your machine and it's display and plugging your own equipment there. I believe it's called XY problem, when you believe your problem has something to do with X, but the effects you describe would probably be affected much more by Y.

Comment: "I have a quantum signalling system which is kind of steam-gothic"  You need to pick one of steam-gothic and quantum, as they are fundamentally different.  Our modern solid state computers can be implemented in steam-gothic (albeit with limits).  Quantum is another kind of beast altogether.  It has to be made of quantum particles--thus the name.  There's no steam-gothic version of a qbit.

Comment: I voted to close this as unclear because AT LEAST (a) your title suggests an aerial construction but the body suggests a terrestrial construction, (b) you don't know how the machine operates but you want us to provide the materials for construction (only a governments can do that), (c) and at the end, you're interested in the operation of the machine rather than the materials of construction.

Comment: What the heck is a "**quantum** signalling system"? Do you even know what "quantum" means or did you just throw in that word because it sounded cool?

Answer (score 1):

**Rationally I'd say no but this isn't a rational question soo**

Engineering the tower and the display relatively simple matters the real question is human proofing it.

Putting a big object in the midst of a species capable of tearing down mountains and altering oceans and then telling them 'it's forbidden', **enforcing that is that hard part**.

Short of cladding it in black dwarf matter (arguable then) there is no substance imaginable that given enough time we couldn't break through. So the engineering focus shifts to offensive measures.

- It would need long range auto targeting rapid fire turrets capable of intercepting threats miles away.
- Infinite energy source.
- It would need to hover and move itself to thwart subterranean attacks.

The reason I focus so heavily on the physical defenses is because once you allow unrestricted physical access to your computer be it quantum or not, it can be compromised in some way.